# I wonder if there will be peace

Tags: meaning

> I am big and round,
>
> I wonder if there will be peace,
>
> I hear sound of the people who are being killed,
>
> I see the people crying for life,
>
> I want to help the poor people.

It is a line encountered in a simple poem of 6th class. But I've been unable to reach the exact meaning of the sentence. Which of the following senses does the expression suit?

1) I feel it as a wonder if the earth is peaceful.

2) I politely request all to be peaceful.

3) I doubt if there is peace at all.

4) Anything else

Comment: Poetry is not generally designed to convey exact meanings. Sometimes the ambiguity is part of the intention of the poem. In any case, could you quote the surrounding context of the poem? It would help interpret it.

Comment: @ChinnabatthinaSivaKumar Please edit several lines of the poem into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the word [wonder](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/wonder_1) is a verb, it means (in this context):

> [intransitive/transitive] to think about something because you want to know more facts or details about it

So, the sentence from the poem, rephrased in a more prosaic way, would mean this:

> "I am interested to know whether there will be peace or not.